# draw a shape like that picture on android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to write an android app which draws window shapes. I search lots of the resources but I couldn't decide where I should start.
I looked at the OpenGL, but it looks a little bit complicated(learning curve is high). I looked at other android graph framework enginees, relativly,simple but not well documented.
I need to draw something like this pic.
[image]
How can I do that.
Can you suggest a path to me to draw something like this.

Comment: I guess OpenGL is the way to go. No shying away from that

Comment: I dont know if it works on android but Java2D also can be a nice option for 2d Drawing. Its easy and intuitive

Comment: Android has fairly extensive 2D drawing that should be perfectly suitable to handle this. Check out the `Drawable` class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html ), and explore its subclasses. You can even define the shapes as resources in XML, which may be easier than writing the Java code.